# How to gathering 2 rows of list to be 1 row for call ContextMenu

Tags: android, listview, contextmenu, listactivity

How to gathering 2 rows of list to be 1 row for call Context Menu

Does anybody have some demo?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What?  You mean have two list items invoke the same context menu?

Comment: I mean in each list I have 2 lines and each line come from difference database table , someone told me to use inflate ListView but I don't know how to use it.

Comment: Sorry, your question makes no sense.  Please explain in much greater detail what exactly you are trying to accomplish, what you have tried, and what isn't working.

Comment: I've code program which extends ListActivity and all I want is when I long press at list it will show contextMenu but unfortunately in each list I have 2 lines so I can't do contextMenu in list with 2 lines so I need to gather 2 lines to be 1 line by use inflate (someone told me that can gather list which have 2 rows to be 1 row ) and then I can make contextMenu with list which have 2 lines

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like all you need a `ListView` with a complex layout for each list view item.

Lots of options.  Create a layout file with the two row layout that you want.  Then, either use a [SimpleAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleAdapter.html), or use an [ArrayAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html) and override the [getView][3] function to fill in the details.

If you search on any of those terms, you should find plenty of tutorials.

[3]: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#getView(int, android.view.View, android.view.ViewGroup)